# Cannot see UIBinder output when rename-to attribute removed from module in GWT application

Tags: gwt

I have a module hellomvp.gwt.xml with rename-to="hellomvp.gwt" and application works fine. But When I remove this **remove-to** attribute I don't see any output rendered. Why?

and in the html file, I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../hellomvp/hellomvp.nocache.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is hellomvp.gwt.xml really in the default package, at the root of your source folder?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you will get a 404 - File not found. That happened because ou removed the rename-to attribute.

In case you are removing the rename-to-attribute, you have to change the script tag to something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="[package-name of the module descriptor location]/[package-name of the module descriptor location].hellomvp.nocache.js"></script>
```

The src atribute is relativ to your host page, so the path might be different.

Compile your project and take a look at your war/webcontent-folder. There you can see what are the correct paths.

Comment: not 404 because Host page gets loaded but not the UIBinder fails to load. I got the clear picture after looking into War content. The web contents are generate in separate convention using or without using rename-to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@EI's answer is good.
with/out rename-to attribute builds the war content in different path convention thus to include js is slightly different.

if the package is **com.example.test** containing **test.gwt.xml**

**war content : without rename-to in module**

- war

  - com.example.test.test

    - test.nocache.js

thus in < script > tag

src="com.example.test.test/com.example.test.test.nocache.js"

**war content : with rename-to="test" in module**

- war

  - test

    - test.nocache.js

thus in < script > tag

src="../test/test.nocache.js"